# How to group a list by n elements, where n is defined in a list

Tags: python

I'm looking for a more "pythonic" way to do the following, or something more simple:

```
   lista = [2,4,6,8,3,4,6,2,1,4,23]
   splitby = [2,4,2,3]
```

expected output, group elements in lista by splitby:

```
grouped = [[2,4],[6,8,3,4],[6,2],[1,4,23]]
```

sum(splitby) will always = len(lista)

Here is what I came out with:

```
grouped = [[] for _ in xrange(len(splitby))]

for x in range(len(splitby)):
    for z in range(splitby[x]):
        grouped[x].append(lista[z + sum(splitby[0:x])])


>>> print grouped
[[2, 4], [6, 8, 3, 4], [6, 2], [1, 4, 23]]
```

Any simple ways to do this using `groupby`, for example?

Comment: ahh, didnt see these duplicates...

Comment: Ahh well ... At least I posted the same answer as @DSM -- It's always nice to independently reproduce one of his answers :-)

Comment: @mgilson All the great minds ... ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I'd use itertools...

```
from itertools import islice
ilista = iter(lista)
groups = [list(islice(ilista, 0, n)) for n in splitby]
```

And, just to convince myself that it actually works... Here it is in action:

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> lista = [2,4,6,8,3,4,6,2,1,4,23]
>>> splitby = [2,4,2,3]
>>> ilista = iter(lista)
>>> groups = [list(islice(ilista, 0, n)) for n in splitby]
>>> print(groups)
[[2, 4], [6, 8, 3, 4], [6, 2], [1, 4, 23]]
```